# jQuery: how does one disable everything inside a div? but still keep everything visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The goal is to disable all the links, when one is clicked, and then disable all the links until the server sends an undisable command (using a similar method that would be used to disable).

So, since all the links are in one containing div, I figure I could just temporarily disable that.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to disable the default link behaviour, you can use a combination of `delegate` and `event.preventDefault`:

```
$('#container').delegate('a', 'click', function(e) {
    if (linksDisabled) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

You can then set `linksDisabled` (in a parent scope) to `true` or `false` in your other event handlers as appropriate.

If these links are doing Javascripty things, it's a bit trickier. It would probably be easiest to put the `if (linksDisabled)` check in each event handler.

Comment: Is there an advantage to using `preventDefault()` instead of `return false;`?

Comment: @Lèse majesté It allows propagation to continue. I personally find it more intuitive. Furthermore, it can be called at any point in the event handler, rather than only at the end. This isn't relevant here, but I like my code to be consistent.

Comment: @DerNalia Set `linksDisabled` to `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#YOUR_DIV a").click(function(){
 return false;
})
```

Comment: If there are other event handlers on the elements, this may well execute after the others and therefore have no effect at all.

Comment: That might be a good way to disable JavaScript links. However, you'd need a way to make sure this event handler fired off first.